# Rails4 can't change the database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails4 app,my `database.yml` is used to be :

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: ph
  server: localhost
  username: phuser
  password: phuser


development:
  <<: *default
```

It worked fine

But now I change the file to :

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: ph
  server: why
  username: phuser
  password: phuser


development:
  <<: *default
```

It works fine well.

So why is this?How I can change the config to connect another database server?

Comment: Have you tried to reload you app server? Just in case, the database.yml settings aren't updated without it or using something to automaticly reload app for you on file change (guard, zeus, etc.)

Comment: It seems that the databse config has no option `server`,but `host` ??

Comment: Yes, I've looked into my configs - there is `host`, but no `server`.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) you can find that the string for configuring the server hostname is actually `host` not server

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database
  host: localhost
```